How to convert javax.servlet request, response objects to jakarta.servlet request,response objects and vice versa
I am migrating my Java project from javax.* to jakarta.* package naming. But some external libraries need javax request objects. I don't have ownership of these external libraries. So I need some workaround for how to deal with these external libraries.
IntelliJ idea gave me suggestion to typecast request object to javax when I am sending it to external library and typecaste to jakarta when I use the objects. Using this method my project do build and war is made. But on runtime it is giving error typecasting don't work here.
Please help me any other alternative.

Typecasting won't work, they are different classes as far as the JVM is concerned, even though they are structurally equivalent. If the external libraries get the servlet objects from your code, e.g. as method arguments (as opposed to using a mechanism that is out of your control), you could create implementations of the javax variants of HttpServletRequest and response that delegate to an instance of the jakarta variant. Just like the HttpServletRequestWrapper.

“from jakarta to javax” — did you mean the opposite direction? I presume so, and edited your prose.

@BasilBourque from javax to jakarta - is upgrade, otherwise is downgrade, but the abovelinked duplicate teaches you how to use both.
